# Presence of unaccounted conditional nodes in TensorBoard

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

### The Problem

When I run my training, my preprocessing examples are successfully created, however my training does not start. Much weirder is the fact, that on analyzing my TensorBoard graph, I see some extra conditional nodes which do not exist in the code. I want to know where and why do these extra nodes come into picture and exactly why the training does not begin. Below is a systematic description of the situation :

**TensorFlow Graph**
The following TensorBoard diagram shows my graph :
[image]
The code which constructs this graph is below

```
def getconv2drelu(inputtensor, kernelsize, strides, padding, convname,
                  imagesummaries=False):
    weights = tf.get_variable("weights", shape=kernelsize, dtype=tf.float32,
                              initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(0,
                                                                          0.01),
                              regularizer=tf.nn.l2_loss)
    biases = tf.get_variable("biases", shape=kernelsize[3], dtype=tf.float32,
                             initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.0))

    conv = tf.nn.conv2d(input=inputtensor, filter=weights, strides=strides,
                        padding=padding, name=convname)
    response = tf.nn.bias_add(conv, biases)
    if imagesummaries:
        filters = (weights - tf.reduce_min(weights)) / (tf.reduce_max(
            weights) - tf.reduce_min(weights))
        filters = tf.transpose(filters, [3, 0, 1, 2])
        tf.summary.image(convname + " filters", filters,
                         max_outputs=kernelsize[3])
    response = tf.nn.relu(response)
    activation_summary(response)
    return response


def getfullyconnected(inputtensor, numinput, numoutput):
    weights = tf.get_variable("weights", shape=[numinput, numoutput],
                              dtype=tf.float32,
                              initializer=
                              tf.truncated_normal_initializer(0, 0.01))
    biases = tf.get_variable("biases", shape=[numoutput], dtype=tf.float32,
                             initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(
                                 0, 0.01))
    response = tf.add(tf.matmul(inputtensor, weights), biases)
    response = tf.nn.relu(response)
    activation_summary(response)
    return response


def inference(inputs):
    with tf.variable_scope("layer1"):
        conv = getconv2drelu(inputtensor=inputs, kernelsize=[7, 7, 3, 96],
                             strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding="VALID",
                             convname="conv1", imagesummaries=True)
        pool = tf.nn.max_pool(conv, [1,  3, 3, 1], strides=[1, 3, 3, 1],
                              padding="SAME", name="pool1")

    with tf.variable_scope("layer2"):
        conv = getconv2drelu(inputtensor=pool, kernelsize=[7, 7, 96, 256],
                             strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding="VALID",
                             convname="conv2", imagesummaries=False)
        pool = tf.nn.max_pool(conv, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1],
                              padding="SAME", name="pool2")

    with tf.variable_scope("layer3"):
        conv = getconv2drelu(inputtensor=pool, kernelsize=[7, 7, 256, 512],
                             strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding="SAME",
                             convname="conv3", imagesummaries=False)

    with tf.variable_scope("layer4"):
        conv = getconv2drelu(inputtensor=conv, kernelsize=[3, 3, 512, 512],
                             strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding="SAME",
                             convname="conv4", imagesummaries=False)

    with tf.variable_scope("layer5"):
        conv = getconv2drelu(inputtensor=conv, kernelsize=[3, 3, 512, 1024],
                             strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding="SAME",
                             convname="conv5", imagesummaries=False)

    with tf.variable_scope("layer6"):
        conv = getconv2drelu(inputtensor=conv, kernelsize=[3, 3, 1024, 1024],
                             strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding="SAME",
                             convname="conv6", imagesummaries=False)
        pool = tf.nn.max_pool(conv, [1, 3, 3, 1], strides=[1, 3, 3, 1],
                              padding="SAME", name="pool1")

        pool = tf.contrib.layers.flatten(pool)

    with tf.variable_scope("fc1"):
        fc = getfullyconnected(pool, 5 * 5 * 1024, 4096)
        drop = tf.nn.dropout(fc, keep_prob=0.5)

    with tf.variable_scope("fc2"):
        fc = getfullyconnected(drop, 4096, 4096)
        drop = tf.nn.dropout(fc, keep_prob=0.5)

    with tf.variable_scope("fc3"):
        logits = getfullyconnected(drop, 4096, 1000)

    return logits
```

The complete TensorBoard graph is shown below :
[image]

The figure is too small, but you  can see a series of pink nodes to the left. An expanded version of such a segment is shown below :

[image]

Expansion of one of the condition blocks ( all blocks are similar !!) is shown below :
[image]

I am unable to understand the presence and existence of these extra condition blocks. All my images when fed to the graph are of size `[221, 221, 3]`.

You can also see that inside a condition block, there is an `isVariableInitialized` test. I do initialize my variables right after the launch of a session. So, I do not understand as to why these checks will be performed.**I have figured out that these condition blocks are there due to the use `tf.get_variable()` which checks for the initialization** Do they cause any performance difference ?

**Another observation**
When I decrease the batchsize, the size of my tensorboard file also decreases. But the nodes shown on the graph remain the same. **Why is this so ?**

My training code is as follows :

```
with tf.control_dependencies(putops):
    train_op = tf.group(apply_gradient_op, variables_averages_op)
sess.run(train_op) # tf.Session() as been defined before sess.run()
```

And putops is initialized to `[]` and during graph construction for each GPU, it is populated as follows :

```
# cpu_compute_stage is appended only once since it corresponds to centralized preprocessing
cpu_compute_stage = data_flow_ops.StagingArea(
                    [tf.float32, tf.int32],
                    shapes=[images_shape, labels_shape]
                )
                cpu_compute_stage_op = gpu_copy_stage.put(
                    [host_images, host_labels])
                putops.append(gpu_copy_stage_op)
# For each device the putops is further appended by gpu_compute_stage which is for each GPU since CPU-GPU copy has to take place
                with tf.device('/gpu:%d' % i):
                    with tf.name_scope('%s_%d' % (TOWER_NAME, i)) as scope:
                        gpu_compute_stage = data_flow_ops.StagingArea(
                            [tf.float32, tf.int32],
                            shapes=[images_shape, labels_shape]
                        )
                        gpu_compute_stage_op = gpu_compute_stage.put(
                            [host_images, host_labels]
                            )
                        putops.append(gpu_compute_stage_op)
```

However, my code does not run despite the fact that I do initialize both global and local variables.

Comment: Hi, 
Did you found a solution ? 
I have the same problem. It occurs when I use `tf.data.Dataset` ! 
I'm making investigations ..